# Azure Service Bus Queue BrokeredMessage throws “SessionLockLostException” on 'RenewLock ()'

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, brokeredmessage

I use Azure Service Bus Queue to receive message and start a long running activity which can last from couple of minutes to couple of hours. During the activity a separate thread renews lock each 30 secs until activity is complete. On BrokeredMessage.RenewLock(), exception occurred, full trace below: "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SessionLockLostException" (This happened for the first time)

Here is the code that renews lock

```
Timer resetToken = new System.Threading.Timer (e => RenewLockQueueJobMessage (), null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds (30));
private void RenewLockQueueJobMessage ()
{
   brokeredMessage.RenewLock ();
 }
```

Configuration of Queue:

```
QueueDescription queueDescription = new QueueDescription (queueName);
queueDescription.EnablePartitioning = true;
queueDescription.RequiresSession = true;
queueDescription.RequiresDuplicateDetection = true;
queueDescription.EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = true;
queueDescription.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
queueDescription.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes (1);
var manager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString (connectionString);
manager.CreateQueue (queueDescription);
```

Exception Trace:

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SessionLockLostException: Channel:uuid:;Link: TrackingId:, SystemTracker:net.tcp:,  ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.ThrowIfFaultMessage(Message wcfMessage)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.HandleMessageReceived(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at 

    Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9_3(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c__DisplayClass8_1.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9_3(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.RenewLockAsyncResult.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__10_1(RenewLockAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult a)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.OnEndRenewMessageLocks(IAsyncResult result)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.ExceptionExtensions.ThrowException(Exception exception)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ReceiveContext.EndRenewLock(IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ReceiveContext.EndRenewLock(IAsyncResult result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your queue requires a session and using partitioned entity. [`SessionLockLostException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.sessionlocklostexception?view=azure-dotnet) will happen sooner or later and you should retry receiving and processing. Message will be picked up again and will be reprocessed by the consumer or another instance if you're scaled out.

Additionally

1. You could change `MaxLockDuration` to 5 mins and reduce timer frequency to issue lock renewal.
2. Consider OnMessage API with auto renewal to simplify lock renewal in your code and exception handling. This [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/GettingStarted/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/BasicSendReceiveUsingQueueClient) can help.

Comment: Sean, this exception occurs at the mid of a long running activity , I need to recover form exception at same instance and at same state. receiving and processing again will restart the activity. Is there anything I can do to resume the activity after the exception? any workaround to prevent exception ?

Comment: If you lock is lost I'm afraid there's nothing you can do. The message is up for grabs and you can't perform and disposition operation on it. That's the nature of the beast. If you need to have a long running operation that should not fail because of the lock, you'd need to resort to out of handler/callback processing. But that sounds like a breaking change to your architecture.